# Coloring a cell with contingent information in gt

Tags: r, colors, gt

I am trying to colour the cell in each row that has the maximum value using the gt package (i.e. colour the maximum value per Type). The following fails:

```
df <- tibble(Type=c("a","b","c"),V2=c(7:9), V3 = c(9,8,1), V4 = c(12,31,105))
df %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    tab_style(
        style = list(
            cell_fill(color = "#D9654B")
        ),
        locations = cells_body(
            columns = vars(V2, V3, V4), # not needed if coloring all columns
            rows = max(.))
    )
```

Please assist with ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding three separate tab_style() calls

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Type=c("a","b","c"),V2=c(7:9), V3 = c(9,8,1), V4 = c(12,31,105))

 df %>%  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#D9654B")
    ) ,
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars(V2), 
      rows = V2 == max(V2))
  ) %>% 
    tab_style(
      style = list(
        cell_fill(color = "#D9654B")
      ) ,
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = vars(V3), 
        rows = V3 == max(V3))
    ) %>% 
    tab_style(
      style = list(
        cell_fill(color = "#D9654B")
      ) ,
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = vars(V4), 
        rows = V4 == max(V4))
    )
```

[image: example]